Only show Last X days based on date slicer selection
So far in Power BI, I have been using a filter to display the last 60 days (including today) as a Relative Date on the given view. (“M.Date_Time” is the column, which stores a lot of dates) I would like the user to be able to parameterize this between 1 to 60 days in the visualization with a slider, with which I can set how many days back the data should be displayed on the view.
It should look like this
How should I do the DAX function?
My version: 2.117.984.0 64-bit (2023. May)

if you want to use a card, then you need to create different measure to get the output.
Measusre =
SUMX (
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[date] <= TODAY ()
            && 'Table'[date]
                >= TODAY () - Parameter[Parameter Value] + 1
    ),
    'Table'[amount]
)



maybe you can try this.
Create a number parameter

then create a measure
MEASURE =
IF (
    MAX ( 'date'[Date] ) <= TODAY ()
        && MAX ( 'date'[Date] )
            >= TODAY () - Parameter[Parameter Value] + 1,
    1,
    0
)

add this measure to the visual filter and set to 1


It works more or less like this, I can apply it to many visualizations on the page and it does its job. For example, it does not allow me to apply it to a card containing a number of pieces. More precisely, I can drag it onto it, but it does not allow me to change the filter to 1.
